# Distributing Objects on a Plane with Defined Probability in Blender

Tags: geometry-nodes, collections

I'm looking to distribute my objects from a collection on a plane with defined occurrence probabilities. @quellenform response in [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265756/control-over-attributes-of-individual-objects-of-a-collection-info-node-part-2?newreg=42f10143dca84e1ca6b14c7ace342b9c) essentially answers the question. However, I'm having trouble getting the [provided code](https://blend-exchange.com/b/pkA19D1Z/) to work to the extent that I only get one type of object instead of four.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! You would have to have four different objects in a collection for this to work. Give it a try. Otherwise, please share your blend file so that I can take a closer look.

Comment: I just used your provided [blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/pkA19D1Z/). There are 4 objects in the source collection ... So I must be doing something wrong, but I don't know what yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, but I've just successfully tested the attached blend file with versions 3.1 to 4.0, and it works exactly as described. Did you open the file directly or did you modify something? Can you tell us a bit more about your problem?

Comment: Blender update from 3.0.1 to 4.0.1 did the trick! Sorry for the confusion!