# Distributing Objects on a Plane with Defined Probability and individual translation/rotation/scale in Blender

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, collections

I am looking for a solution to distribute my objects from a collection on a plane with defined occurrence probabilities. However, I would like the individual objects to be rotated and moved randomly. Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be realized?

The [distribution part](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265756/control-over-attributes-of-individual-objects-of-a-collection-info-node-part-2?newreg=42f10143dca84e1ca6b14c7ace342b9c) is already realized at this point, for example, but unfortunately all objects have a uniform orientation.

---

**Update**:
Unchecking "Pick Instance" and deleting the ID link to instance ID:
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try to plugin a random vector into the rotation of instance on points?

Comment: Unfortunately only rotates all objects together, but i want an individual rotation for each object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were able to instantiate the objects with the existing setup according to your wishes, and only the rotation of the individual instances is necessary, you could solve this as follows:

[image]

Here I simply rotate the individual instances with a random value, but use the index of the individual instances as a control for generating the random rotation.

*Explanation:*
The existing setup assigns a specific ID to the object groups, which means that this cannot be used directly to generate a unique rotation for the individual instances. I therefore use the index here instead.