Control instance ratio in geometry nodes
I'm struggling to control the instance ratio in geometry nodes like you are able to do in the particle system.
In the particle system you can choose the collection and lets say you want 3 cones, 3 ico spheres and 1 torus. I'm looking to do the exact same in geometry nodes but I'm unable to figure out how.


Unfortunately, there is (currently) no comparable option in Geometry Nodes. However, you could control the distribution in this way: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265756

Thank you! I will look into it better tomorrow :)

I guess it's important to know whether you want the selections to be ordered, as in particle 'Use Count' .. or just  random in the right ratio

The second :) random is okay, it just has to be in the right ratio.
